# C# deserializes json with multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON file into 3 variables:
manager(Class)
Servers(list-class)
Admins(List-Class)

Everything I've tried so far doesn't work. How should I do that?

```
{
   "Manager":{
      "ServerIp":"ServerIP",
      "ServerPort":"6000"
   },
   "Admins":[
      {
         "Name":"AdminUserName",
         "ID":"AdminID"
      }
   ]
   "Servers":[
      {
         "ServerName":"servername",
         "Path":"executablepath",
         "IP":"ip",
         "Port":"port",
         "Password":"pass"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
public class Manager
{
    public string? ServerIp { get; set; }
    public  string? ServerPort { get; set; }
}
public class Admins
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? ID { get; set; }
}

public class Servers
{
    public string? ServerName { get; set; }
    public string? Path { get; set; }
    public string? IP { get; set; }
    public string? Port { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, look at your json. What is the root object? It's a json object with three properties. Just create a model class that _precisely_ reflects this root json object with its three properties (including the correct types appropriate for the kind of values these properties have) and deserialize your json to that model class.

Comment: This is not valid JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another class that precisely matches the structure of the JSON that you're describing:

```
public class Info // come up with a better name than "Info"...
{
   public Manager Manager { get; set; }
   public List<Admins> Admins { get; set; }
   public List<Servers> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

Then just deserialize the contents of this file into an instance of this class, for example (using `System.Text.Json`):

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);
var info = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Info>(json);
```

Then just read the properties of `info` as you need them (`Manager`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get the following exception with this code: 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'Admins', line 12, position 3."

Comment: @Toni Because your JSON is invalid and is missing a comma

Comment: @Toni specifically missing ',' after `"Admins": [...]"`.

Answer (score 0):

here is an equivalent **JSON** model to your desired **C#** types. Nullable types are not recommended to use while working with JSON to C# Models.
[image]